# Spurious 504s from AWS classic load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

I have a REST API running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk that work well most of the time. However, every few hours it hiccups by returning a 504 on a single request. Here's the AWS Elastic Load Balancer (classic) log:

> 2018-03-04T21:07:00.151327Z awseb-e-x-AWSEBLoa-abc123  xxx.xxx.xxx.216:57324 - -1 -1 -1 504 0 2497 0 "POST https://my.api.com:443/v1/data/add HTTP/1.1" "-" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA TLSv1

Here's the log in context:

> 2018-03-04T21:07:54.884768Z awseb-e-x-AWSEBLoa-abc123  xxx.xxx.xxx.216:57339 xxx.xxx.xxx.85:80 0.000041 0.134478 0.000084 200 200 2672 93 "POST https://my.api.com:443/v1/data/add HTTP/1.1" "-" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA TLSv1
>   2018-03-04T21:07:55.935722Z awseb-e-x-AWSEBLoa-abc123  xxx.xxx.xxx.216:57342  xxx.xxx.xxx.85:80 0.000067 0.107369 0.000075 200 200 5538 93 "POST https://my.api.com:443/v1/data/add HTTP/1.1" "-" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA TLSv1
>   2018-03-04T21:07:56.633812Z awseb-e-x-AWSEBLoa-abc123  xxx.xxx.xxx.226:33815  xxx.xxx.xxx.85:80 0.000041 0.149562 0.000079 200 200 332 93 "POST https://my.api.com:443/v1/data/add HTTP/1.1" "-" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2
>   2018-03-04T21:07:00.151327Z awseb-e-x-AWSEBLoa-abc123  xxx.xxx.xxx.216:57324 - -1 -1 -1 504 0 2497 0 "POST https://my.api.com:443/v1/data/add HTTP/1.1" "-" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA TLSv1
>   2018-03-04T21:08:00.521384Z awseb-e-x-AWSEBLoa-abc123  xxx.xxx.xxx.226:45505  xxx.xxx.xxx.85:80 0.000037 0.172259 0.000072 200 200 334 93 "POST https://my.api.com:443/v1/data/add HTTP/1.1" "-" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2
>   2018-03-04T21:08:02.896099Z awseb-e-x-AWSEBLoa-abc123  xxx.xxx.xxx.226:55647  xxx.xxx.xxx.112:80 0.000041 0.166058 0.000064 200 200 334 93 "POST https://my.api.com:443/v1/data/add HTTP/1.1" "-" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2
>   2018-03-04T21:08:08.914958Z awseb-e-x-AWSEBLoa-abc123  xxx.xxx.xxx.226:10771  xxx.xxx.xxx.85:80 0.000046 0.173661 0.000091 200 200 341 93 "POST https://my.api.com:443/v1/data/add HTTP/1.1" "-" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 
>   ```

There is no correlated loss of healthiness reported in the logs on the actual ec2 instances.

It seems to go away for a couple of days after rebuilding the underlying ec2 instances.

Comment: Is it the Beanstalk app returning 504 through the ELB, or the ELB itself returning it (gateway timeout).

Comment: @jarmod - it's the ELB itself. The requests aren't even making it to the beanstalk nodes.

Comment: Have you investigated any of the suggestions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http504

Comment: There is something very odd about your log entries. For the HTTP requests that succeed, the times increase normally. For the failed request, the time is 2018-03-04T21:07:00.151327Z which is almost a minute before the previous entry of 2018-03-04T21:07:56.633812Z. Go back in time in your log and see if there were other 504 errors at that time.

Comment: @JohnHanley the log entry shows the request arrival time, and its placement here suggests a 60 second timeout.  If there are other 504s that began around the same time, they should also be logged out of sequence... but a closer check of the logs around that time both here and at the instances is still a good suggestion. This entry suggests that the ELB did not send the request to any instance, but I have long suspected that classic balancer logs sometimes seem to claim that a failed request did not go to any instance when in fact it did.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot. Agreed. If there are other errors around the same time, this would indicate a health check failure. If there are successes both immediately before and after that time, then something else is going on. My bet is that either the health check is too tight / not setup correctly or that the user has a small T2 instance that is being throttled. Not enough data from the questioner on his configuration and setup.

Comment: @JohnHanley - running 2 t2.micros, both have plenty of CPU credits and are not being throttled. ELB idle timeout is default of 60 seconds; NGINX keepalive timeout is default of 65 seconds.

Comment: Did you review your log for the time that I suggested? Did any other requests fail near that time? Your issue looks like a request was sent to your instance that timed out. Also review the log files for your instance for that time and compare. Note: I find T2.micro just too small to do anything with. Opinions vary on this matter. Try a larger instance for a period of time and see if the errors stop.

Comment: @JohnHanley - I did. No problems. I think I found the problem though - having to do with incorrectly set NGINX proxy settings. I had proxy_connect_timeout, proxy_send_timeout, and proxy_read_timeout all set to 1800s. I removed these from the .ebextensions and I haven't seen on error for about 24 hours. Do you think this could have been the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was bad proxy configs in my .ebextensions directory, specifically too high of values for `proxy_connect_timeout`, `proxy_send_timeout`, and `proxy_read_timeout`:

`files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            client_max_body_size 500m;
            proxy_buffers 8 16k;
            proxy_buffer_size 32k;
            proxy_connect_timeout 1800s;
            proxy_send_timeout 1800s;
            proxy_read_timeout 1800s;
            gzip on;
            gzip_vary on;
            gzip_proxied any;
            gzip_comp_level 4;
            gzip_static on;
            gzip_http_version 1.1;
            gzip_min_length 256;
            gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;`

I had originally set these in attempt to to allow large uploads, but this was erroneous. Removing the settings and redeploying worked like a charm.